# C3 chart doesn't work in a modal window?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, c3.js

I have used angular c3 charts in http://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html website with angular js.I could use these charts in a normal angular controller,but when i used it in a modal window it does not display any chart.And i have also checked another few libraries like tc-angular-chart js. they also don't work on a modal window

Comment: post a fiddle or plunker please...

Comment: http://jettro.github.io/c3-angular-directive/#getstarted...might help since i am able to plot a graph in modal window.